# android - footer in LinearLayout invisible

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to create a layout composed of:
- Header
- Central GridView
- Footer

this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gridrelativelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--  Header -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/header" >

                <!-- Logo -->
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/header"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="top"/>
                <!-- /Logo -->
        </LinearLayout>

    <!-- /Header -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

      <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--  Footer -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/header" >

             <!-- Logo -->
                <ImageView 
                    android:src="@drawable/footer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
             <!-- /Logo -->   
        </LinearLayout>

    <!-- /Footer -->

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know why but i can't display the footer, even if i set its layout gravity as "bottom"..anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your `grid_layout` layout_height at match_parent, it will fill the rest of the space of the LinearLayout.  You need to either switch to a RelativeLayout, make the `grid_layout` have a height of wrap_content, or give your `footer` a negative margin (this will cause it to be drawn over the `grid_layout`).

You can also try experimenting with layout_weight for your `grid_layout` and `footer` views.  Giving them a weight should share the remaining space between them on the screen.

Comment: I've already tried with relative layout and setting the height with wrap_content, but in that case all the layout fills half screen and the rest is empty

Comment: If you use a `RelativeLayout`, make sure the parent (the RelativeLayout) has a height of match_parent.  Then align the footer view with alignParentBottom, and set your grid_layout to be above the footer with the layout_above attribute.

Comment: thank you, i've followed this last advice and now it is perfect! you saved me:)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Relative layout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:numColumns="3" >

    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap of graphical layout

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding -- android:layout_weight="1"

```
<!--  Header -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/header" >

            <!-- Logo -->
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/header"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"/>
            <!-- /Logo -->
    </LinearLayout>

<!-- /Header -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<!--  Footer -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/header" >

         <!-- Logo -->
            <ImageView 
                android:src="@drawable/footer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
         <!-- /Logo -->   
    </LinearLayout>

<!-- /Footer -->
```

Comment: in this case the footer appears, but half screen remains empty!